# Looping over an array with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation

Over on SO I posted a question: [Change transition duration during loop with requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51491008/1682405) which hasn't got any responses just yet. I've since come up with this idea and wanted to know if there was any way to improve it.

Essentially I would like to loop over an array of elements that have a smooth transition (a different state to normal) when swapping between them.

Instead of setting a `setTimeout` during `Array.forEach`, then using `requestAnimationFrame` to loop over the whole thing. I'm now using `requestAnimationFrame` for the main loop and `Array.shift`ing to work on the current element.

Any ideas for improvement? Is this efficient?

```
function animateArray(fooArray, bar) {

    // Timing
    var start = null;
    var interval = 3000; // how long each element in the array will be displayed for
    var intro = 1000; // easing/tweening in duration
    var outro = 1000; // easing/tweening out duration
    var last = 0 // The last interval, 
    var current; //current element of array
    var fooLength = fooArray.length;

    function update(timestamp) {

        // get the start time and progress
        if (!start) start = timestamp;
        var progress = timestamp - start;

        // do something every `interval` seconds (if it can)
        if(!last || timestamp - last >= interval) {
            last = timestamp;

            // pull off the first element in the array to work on
            current = fooArray.shift();
        }

        if (typeof current !== null) {

            // Do something during the intro
            if (timestamp < last + intro) {
                console.log(`${current}-intro`);

            // The main animation
            } else if (timestamp > last + intro && timestamp < last + (interval - outro)) {
                console.log(`${current}`);

            // do something else during the outro
            } else {
                console.log(`${current}-outro`);
            }
        }

        // loop
        if (progress < interval * fooLength) {
            requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => update(timestamp, fooArray, bar));
        }

    };

    requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => update(timestamp, fooArray, bar));
}

animateArray([1,2,3], 'bar');
```